# How to retrieve single data in a list view in android

Tags: android

I am using built in list view to display data from the database in a list format,which displays name and contact number in the same line.I want to modify the names or numbers .So how can I get both name and number separately in a custom list view and displayed in some other text fields.
I tried using onTouchListener but this returns both the name and the number.

My code to display name and contact number as a list :

```
package com.example.hp.panic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Modify extends Activity {

    SQLiteDatabase database;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modify);
        try {
            database = openOrCreateDatabase("myDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, 
null);

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);

            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

            Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts ", null);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    String data = c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1);
                    arrayList.add(data);
                    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Modify.this, "Table Empty", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            c.close();

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
    view,int i, long l) {
                     switch (i) {
                        case 0: {

                        }
                        break;
                        case 1: {
                            //Intent intent = new 
   // Intent(Modify.this,Modify2.class);
                                //startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            break;
                            case 2: {
                                //Intent intent = new 
    //Intent(Modify.this,Modify2.class);
                                //startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            break;
                             case 3: {
                                //Intent intent = new Intent(Modify.this, 
       //Modify2.class);  
                                //startActivity(intent);
                            }
                             break;
                             case 4: {
                              /*  Intent intent = new Intent(Modify.this, 
        Modify2.class);
                                startActivity(intent);*/
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                     }
                 });
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 Log.d("Error", String.valueOf(e));
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Could you post some of your code? Are you using a custom adapter with your list view? (i.e. ArrayAdapter or CursorAdapter)

Comment: put your code here

Comment: Add some code !

Comment: I have added my code .Please check it.